# When I use a HEAD method on file download controller I get 404 error

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have a file download Controller in my application and using [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/) I have to render them on browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getCompanySlide(@CurrentUser User user,
                                @RequestParam("userId") String encryptedUserId,
                                @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
                                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        if (user != null){
            Filestore fileStore = fileStoreService.findByUserIdAndFileName(encryptedUserId, fileName);
            fileStoreService.getFile(fileStore, response, true);
        }
    }
```

And the library uses XMLHttpRequest to fetch the file.

```
var c = new XMLHttpRequest;
                c.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    var a, f;
                    4 === c.readyState && ((200 <= c.status && 300 > c.status || 0 === c.status) && (a = c.getResponseHeader("content-type")) && q.some(function (b) {
                        return b.supportsMimetype(a) ? (f = b, console.log("Found plugin by mimetype and xhr head: " + a), !0) : !1
                    }), b(f))
                };

                c.open("HEAD", a, !0);
                c.send()
```

On this Javascript part in c.open function it sends an HEAD request to my controller where it is returning 404 for me. what should be the reason?

Comment: Well, you said it. If you said a HEAD request, it's not going to get mapped to a GET request.

Comment: HEAD just gets the meta information from a GET request isn't it?

Comment: HEAD is an HTTP verb just as much as GET, POST, PUT etc. If you send a HEAD but your method is only mapped to GET requests, your request won't be handled by that method.

Comment: What should be the solution to this?

Comment: [Reference](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-method-head-options-support.html) if you see the link HEAD automatically fetches the header of the response but not body. HEAD is implicitly understood by Spring. But in my case it still shows 404 error.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected! Thanks for the link, I didn't know that. The problem isn't with the HTTP verb then, I can only think that the resource URI is bad - did you forget the context path or something?

Comment: Nope. When I copy the URI and open it in a new tab it opens up with no error. I can't understand why it isn't working in that javascript code.

Comment: I would use the development tools of the browser to check the request that's being sent. Maybe try sending a GET instead of a HEAD and see if that works better? If so, the URL is definitely good

Comment: I tried the GET method, It didn't show me 404 but also didn't fetch the file on ViewerJS.

Comment: I'd argue that you need to add `HEAD` to the `method` parameter, the discarding body thing AFAIK only works if you specify the method - and IMHO that's also the reason why `method` accepts more than one value. i.e.: `@RequestMapping(value = "/getFile", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})`

Comment: Thanks for replies guys. I found that the issue was I have configured my application that any request other than get should have CSRF token in it. So the request was getting denied and that resulted in 404 error.